# what does this conditional mean?

Tags: php

I was reviewing some PHP code and found a block of conditional statements that I couldn't understand .

```
     if ($options['mentionbbcode'] & 8) {
                $final_rendered .= '<span class="highlight">';
        } 
     if ($options['mentionbbcode'] & 4) {
                $final_rendered .= '<i>';
        } 

     if ($options['mentionbbcode'] & 2) {
                $final_rendered .= '<b>';
        }
```

what is the difference between those three conditionals .. shouldn't they all return true if `$options['mentionbbcode']` is set ? 
what is the role of the integer value here ?

Comment: Have a look at [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: Thanks for the response , could you give me example where this statement return true and another where it will return false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [a bitwise and operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

So for example when using `$value = $var & 8`, `$value` will be a number for which the bits that are `1` in both `$var` and `8` are also `1` in the new value.

In your case, these conditions are testing if a certain bit is set for the value, the 4th, 3rd and 2nd to be correct.

**Update:**
Here are some examples of results with different values for the first condition. It tests if the fourth bit from the right is set.

```
12 & 8 // true  (01010 & 01000 => 01000)
15 & 8 // true  (01111 & 01000 => 01000) 
7  & 8 // false (00111 & 01000 => 00000)
17 & 8 // false (10001 & 01000 => 00000)
```

As long as one bit in a number is set, PHP will interpret this as true.

Comment: Thanks for the response , could you give me example where this statement return true and another where it will return false ?

Comment: I added some examples of bitwise calculations